# Relacionar mais de uma tabela para uma única tela de cadastro

Tags: delphi, dbgrid

Eu tenho tela de cadastro de currículos conforme mostrado abaixo.

O que eu precisava fazer é apenas cadastrar, mas o problema é que tenho três cadastro nessa tela, o de informações pessoais, telefones e emails.

A de telefone e emails estão ligadas como chave estrangeiras na do informações pessoais. (Fiz isso para ele poder cadastrar o numero de telefones e emails que ele quiser).

Minha dúvida é a seguinte: quando eu tiver mais de um cadastro, ele vai misturar com outros telefones.

Por exemplo:

Uma pessoa cadastrada, então eu vou la e cadastro vários telefones e emails desta pessoa.
Quando eu for cadastrar a segunda pessoa, os telefones e emails estarão la mostrando ainda, eu gostaria que quando eu pedir pra cadastrar um novo, os dois `dbGrid` fossem limpos e fosse para a outra pessoa.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você esqueceu de comentar que tecnologia está utilizando para realizar o acesso a dados. O que está utilizando? ADO, dbExpress, Firedac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não especificou a tecnologia de acesso a dados que está utilizando, mas você, pelo que pude entender, precisa estabelecer um relacionamento entre a tabela de currículos e a tabela de telefones e *e-mail*, uma forma bastante popular de fazer isso seria utilizando relacionamentos mestre-detalhe.

No Delphi é possível fazer isso através de configuração nos componentes de acesso a dados. No seu `DataSet` da tabela detalhe (telefone ou email) você deve indicar na propriedade `MasterSource` o nome do `DataSource` da tabela mestre (currículos). Também é necessário informar na propriedade `MasterFields` deste `DataSet` os campos chaves que serão utilizados para relacionar as duas tabelas.